# How to add a datepicker in ionic angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, datepicker, ionic-framework

I installed `ionic-datepicker` using bower with this command:

```
bower install ionic-datepicker --save
```

After I put the path of `ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js` in my `index.html` file:

```
<script src="lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

In my application module I injected the dependency ionic-datepicker in order to work with the `ionic-timepicker`.

```
angular.module('mainModuleName', ['ionic', 'ionic-datepicker']){
  //
}
```

Now I am receiving this error :

```
!JavaScript ERROR: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic-datepicker due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic-datepicker' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/nomod?p0=ionic-datepicker
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=ionic-datepicker&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ionic-datepicker'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dionic-datepicker
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20ionic-datepicker%20due%20to%3A%0A%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ionic-datepicker'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dionic-datepicker%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.25%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dionic-datepicker%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520Module%2520'ionic-datepicker'%2520is%2520not%2520available!%2520You%2520either%2520misspelled%2520the%2520module%2520name%2520or%2520forgot%2520to%2520load%2520it.%2520If%2520registering%2520a%2520module%2520ensure%2520that%2520you%2520specify%2520the%2520dependencies%2520as%2520the%2520second%2520argument.%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.25%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dionic-datepicker on line 11532 for http://localhost:40820/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
```

ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js:
[image]

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above -->
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">


        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="js/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>


        <!--your app's js  -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Controllers/inscription.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/Categories.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/SousCategories.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/Evenement.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Controllers/RechercheEvent.js"></script>

        <script src="js/service/services.js"></script>

 </head>
```

Comment: Please check the file ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js is present or not?

Comment: please look my question i edited this, the file ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js is present

Comment: Where is your `index.html` located?

Comment: Could you please share your complete folder structure?

Comment: I just installed this and working perfectly

Comment: please look my question i edited this

Comment: Your complete project folder structure?

Comment: look my question please i edited this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just  uninstall `ionic datepicker` and install again.